# How to parse JSON data in my iOS app

Tags: ios, json

```
items =     (
                {
            "First Name" = Banny ;
            "Last Name" = Teo ;
            "student_no" = 9021074B;
        }
    );
    status = 2;
```

I want to parse/get First Name, Last Name and Student No of above json data in Xcode. Please help me to solve that issue.

Comment: You are using Swift or what?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class. It creates an `NSDictionary` instance with the JSON contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is wrong. You should have square brackets instead of round brackets. Semi-colon should be replaced with comma's.

```
{

   "items": [

      {

         "First Name": "Banny",

         "Last Name": "Teo",

         "student_no": "9021074B"

      }

   ]

}
```

[Good Site](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) for learning JSON

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for get details from JSON data

```
NSDictionary* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJsonData options:0 error:nil];
```